# Solving the invalid name for Python module warning in PyDev

Tags: python, pydev

I encountered the `Invalid name for Python module: ...filename (it'll not be analyzed)` warning message in PyDev and I tried to resolve it by replacing `-` in the filename with `_` but the warning didn't disappeared.

One of the problems is that in fact this is not a module, it's just a python script, still I get the warning and the warning says nothing about how to solve the issue.

What are the real requirements for filenames (not necessary modules) and where are they specified (PIP)?

How do I solve this problem in PyDev?

Comment: A "python script" **is** a python module.

Comment: What is the module name?

Comment: The filename. See my answer for what's valid in a module name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html for information about modules.

To find out what characters are valid, have a look at the [syntax of the `import` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement). It shows you that a [module name](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-module) needs to be a valid identifier which has [the following rule](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
```

Comment: In fact, the problem was the usage of "." in the filename, not the "_", marked as solved.

Comment: The '-' characters is also not valid in filename.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar message and when I checked the script file name, I had a "-" [dash character] in the script name. After I removed the dash character and replaced with " _ " [an under score character], the warning message was gone.

Comment: It's better to ask a separate question if your question is even slightly different. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030905/