# invalid syntax: importing Modules in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> import 23
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I am learning Python and working on modules. I created a module and wanted to import it:

```
import 23
```

However, IDLE gave me an error:

> **SyntaxError**: invalid syntax

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving the invalid name for Python module warning in PyDev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552311/solving-the-invalid-name-for-python-module-warning-in-pydev)

Answer (score 6):

That's an invalid module name in Python - module names must start with a letter or underscore.

Rename your module file to something else like `module23.py` and try importing that.

UPDATE: As pointed out in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552311/solving-the-invalid-name-for-python-module-warning-in-pydev) by user ThiefMaster, the actual rule for a Python module name comes from the [syntax grammar for a Python import statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-module). The rules of interest in this case are

```
import_stmt     ::=  "import" module ["as" name] ( "," module ["as" name] )*
                     | "from" relative_module "import" identifier ["as" name]
                     ( "," identifier ["as" name] )*
                     | "from" relative_module "import" "(" identifier ["as" name]
                     ( "," identifier ["as" name] )* [","] ")"
                     | "from" module "import" "*"
module          ::=  (identifier ".")* identifier
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
```

Tracing down through the parse tree we see that a `module` name is an `identifier` which must start with an underscore or letter and be followed by zero of more letters, digits or underscores.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import hello
ImportError: No module named hello
>>> I am getting this error message although it exists. Why is it occuring?

Comment: @user2446640 Does the corresponding `hello.py` module file exist? Are you in the same directory as the module you're trying to import and/or is the module directory included in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: How to include the module directory in the PYTHONPATH? Yes hello.py exists. Is it necessary to be in the same directory to include the module? Can you please show the syntax!

Comment: @user2446640 This is only tangentially related to your original question of *"Why doesn't `import 23` work?"* I'd recommend you open up another question for your new problem to keep the comments/answers threads separate.