# Avoiding a pylint warning about dash in python script name

Tags: python, pylint

I'm trying to fix all pylint warnings for my code, and there is just one that I cannot fix without disabling the warning or renaming the script:

```
C:  1, 0: Invalid module name "foo-bar" (invalid-name)
```

Renaming the script is not an option since its name is its public interface. The script is widely used under the current name.

That's a top-level program. The file is not intended to be used as a module. If I decide to import it as a module for unit tests, I can use `__import__("foo-bar")` but no other import is supported.

Is there any nice way to tell pylint that it's a top-level script, not a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `module-rgx` option either at the CLI or in your pylintrc file to allow `-`s. For more on this check out [the docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/options.html).

Comment: That's a good suggestion. The downside is that `-` won't be detected in the files that are modules. But I can craft a regex to specifically allow known names. The correct and up-to-date URL is https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/options.html

Comment: All python files are modules to pylint, including executables ... because they are modules to python. You are making a distinction which neither the language nor pylint makes.

Comment: Well actually python does make a distinction between top-level scripts and modules in that top level scripts are named '__main__' and all other module are named based on their file name. This has other implications, e.g. the search path will include the containing directory...